# Multiple if conditions

Tags: python, if-statement

can you please explain to me why this code:

```
if (x and y) and z > 0:
    return True
```

isn't the same as:

```
if (x and y) > 0 < z:
    return True
```

Basically, why cant I chain several variables like:

```
if var1 and var2 and var3 and var4 > 0:
    do_this
```

What am I doing wrong?

**--edit--**
I suppose I just want to know how can I shorten the condition without writing:

```
if var1 > 0 and var2 > 0 and var3 > 0
```

especially if the condition is a long one like:

```
if var1 > (pow(x, 3) / 2.5*pow(y,0.5)+x*y)
```

if would be unfeasible to rewrite the condition for every variable, imagine if I had 10 of those vars.
Or is there a better way which I am not seeing that could be used in situations like this? Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't doing what you imagine:

```
if (x and y) > 0 < z: return True
```

The above evaluates `(x and y)` first, if both are truthy then `y` is returned, so now we have:

```
if y > 0 < z: return True
```

Which is the same as:

```
if y > 0 and 0 < z
```

Clearly, the above isn't the same as the other expression:

```
if (x and y) and z > 0: return True
if y and z > 0:
if z > 0:
```

Bottom line: `(x and y) > 0` is *definitely not* doing what you imagine! what you meant to say must be written like this:

```
 if x > 0 and y > 0 and z > 0: return True
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Is there any way to shorten the expression? Without rewriting x  > 0 and y > 0 and z > 0? So it checks if every listed variable is > 0?

Comment: @metacore there isn't a general solution for comparing multiple values at once. For this case in particular, the expression in the last line of my answer is the simplest way to express the condition